Style does not apply to primevue documentation examples
I'm trying to get the Dialog component of the Primevue library to work. I copied and pasted the example from the documentation and the rendering is nothing like it.
It seems that CSS file imports are missing, but I can't find anything to help me in the documentation.
Here's my App.vue file (example from the documentation) :
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

import { Button } from 'primevue';

const visible = ref(false)
</script>

<template>
<Button label="Show" @click="visible = true" />

<Dialog v-model:visible="visible" modal header="Edit Profile" :style="{ width: '25rem' }">
    <span class="text-surface-500 dark:text-surface-400 block mb-8">Update your information.</span>
    <div class="flex items-center gap-4 mb-4">
        <label for="username" class="font-semibold w-24">Username</label>
        <InputText id="username" class="flex-auto" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex items-center gap-4 mb-8">
        <label for="email" class="font-semibold w-24">Email</label>
        <InputText id="email" class="flex-auto" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-end gap-2">
        <Button type="button" label="Cancel" severity="secondary" @click="visible = false"></Button>
        <Button type="button" label="Save" @click="visible = false"></Button>
    </div>
</Dialog>
</template>

And the main.ts file:
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import App from './App.vue'
import Aura from '@primevue/themes/aura';
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css'

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(PrimeVue, {
  theme: {
      preset: Aura,
      options: {
        prefix: 'p',
      }
  }
});
app.mount("#app");

This is the rendering I get :

Edit:
After adding import 'primeflex/primeflex.css', it's better but I still don't have the same rendering as in the documentation :


debug the issue with browser dev tools.  compare the primevue official example and your app.  it actually looks very close to the official example, clearly most styles are being applied.  maybe something like display: flex is missing or being overridden.  perhaps there is something in your './assets/main.css' or other stylesheet that can explain it, but the DOM inspector dev tool should at least give more clues.

The missing part is Primeflex, which is used in documentation examples and accompanies Primevue without being a part of it.
It should be installed and imported among other styles:
import 'primeflex/primeflex.css'


Thanks for your reply, I've added the new rendering to the question. It's better but I don't get the same rendering as in the documentation. Can you see what else I might have forgotten?

I stand corrected, the docs currently use tailwind which replaced primeflex at some point. You can install tailwindcss@2 and import tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.css, but it's extremely ineffective and it's recommended to integrate it into your setup https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation
